# Intersection under functions Proof: Show that $ \cap _{A \in \mathcal C}f(A)$ is not a subset of $f( \cap_{A\in\mathcal C} A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

*Problem:* Let $\mathcal C$ be a collectiction of subset of a set X. Let Y be a set. Let $f: X \to Y$.

Show that $ \cap _{A \in \mathcal C}f(A)$ is not a subset of $f( \cap_{A\in\mathcal C} A)$

This is a reduced version of this problem. The original called to show the subset relation the other way around. That is, show that $ \cap _{A \in \mathcal C}f(A)\subset f( \cap_{A\in\mathcal C} A)$.

Which was fine, however I now need to prove that the other way doesn't hold, which I can't seem to do. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It can be only be proved that $\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal C}f(A)$ is *not necessarily* a subset of $f(\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal C}A)$.

So actually we need a counterexample.

Let $B,C$ be disjoint non-empty subsets of $X$ and let $f$ be a constant function sending each element of $X$ to $y_0\in Y$.

Then $f(B\cap C)=f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and $f(B)\cap f(C)=\{y_0\}$.

This proves the statement for collection $\mathcal C:=\{B,C\}$.